# Best way to delete "expired" bookings in bookingsystem

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am building a bookingsystem for some student cabins in CodeIgniter. Things are starting to come together, but I have a small issue to solve.

Right before payment, the booking is added to the database, and a datetime-field is set to 0. This field will get the current time, when the payment is confirmed (from paypal). I have already handled if they cancel the payment by pushing the cancel button on paypal. But if there are some errors while trying to set up the payment, or the user closes the window, or the payment times out, the rows will still be in the database. What I want to do is have them deleted after maybe 20 min, if they haven't been given a valid value in the datetime-field.

EDIT: I also have a field for when the row is inserted (when the payment is called).

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Add another date field, `row_created_at` and set it to `NOW()` when you insert the row.

Also set up a cron job that'll delete all rows where `datetime-field` is `null` and `row_created_at` is older than 20 minutes.

Comment: Ahh yes, I have a field like that. Actually, I have heard about these cron jobs, but know little (or nothing) about them. Will I be writing this in PHP? Where do I set up the intervals for this check?

Comment: As @Victor points out, perfomance degradation from those unused rows is pretty much nonexistent. You can run this operation manually every week or so :-)

Comment: And yes, with crontab you can run every program you want, even PHP scripts. Here's [documentation for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Comment: Thx a bunch, I will look into it. Manually is no fun :)

Comment: You might also like to read http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category:Advanced::CronScript for using cron jobs in CI (though a script to just delete some rows should be easy enough as raw PHP)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to add a creation time to your bookings, or you will have no way to distinguish between bookings created three days ago and bookings created three milliseconds ago.

Second, realize that there will be no negative performance consequences to having even several hundred unused rows in a database, so it's more of a "keep the database clean" process than a "delete unused rows as soon as possible" situation.

This means you can run a process at a fixed time (such as every night) that runs a query similar to:

```
DELETE FROM booking WHERE datetime = 0 
                      AND create_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

Adding an index on `datetime` will make this query lightning fast regardless of how many valid bookings end up in that table.